# MySQL Query Sorting with Numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have the following query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT DISTINCT SKU_SIZE_PART1 
                          FROM SKU_DATA 
                          WHERE SKU_BRANDNAME = "'.$brand.'" 
                          ORDER BY SKU_SIZE_PART1 DESC');

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sku_size1 = $row['SKU_SIZE_PART1'];

    echo $sku_size1;
}
```

Basically what is happening is.. the order is all messed up.  This is what comes up:

```
9.50, 8.75, 8.00, 7.50, 7.00, 37, 35, 33, 325, 32, 315, 31, 305, 30, 295
```

325 should come up first, then 315 then so on.

What can I do to make this happen?

Comment: Let me guess SKU_SIZE_PART1 is text...wrong wrong wrong :-[.

Comment: What's the data type of `SKU_SIZE_PART1`?

Comment: What is the type of SKU_SIZE_PART1 ?

Comment: Yeah you guys are right.. it is a varchar(6).  This is a big tire database we bought from a company :-\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `sku_size_part1` into a float.

This will slow your query down, but it will work:

```
$brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($brand);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT sku_size_part1
                          FROM sku_data 
                          WHERE sku_brandname = '$brand' 
                          ORDER BY CAST(sku_size_part1 AS FLOAT) DESC");
```

This will slow the query down, because MySQL will not be able to use an index to do the sorting, using a function prevents that.

A better solution *(if possible)* would be to redefine `sku-size_part1` as a decimal(10,2).

```
-- Make a backup first --
ALTER TABLE sku_data CHANGE sku_size_part1 DECIMAL(10,2);
```

*(Make sure the first parameter (10) and the second parameter (2) are large enough to hold all possible values.)*
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: This works, but instead of casting, it'd be better if Drew altered the table column to a decimal.

Comment: In the past when I had to do something like this, I added a new column to the database in order to leave the original data just in case.  
You could try 
`ALTER TABLE sku_data ADD COLUMN sku_size_part1_dec DECIMAL NULL;`
And then you can do an update:
`UPDATE sku_data SET sku_size_part1_dec = CAST(sku_size_part1 AS DECIMAL)`