# why is mySQL sorting by DESC ranking 9.98 higher than 85.24?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a code that sorts like this:

`SELECT product_id, relevancy FROM db_products ORDER BY relevancy DESC`

The `relevancy` field is updated separately with values ranging from `1.00` to `99.99`

Now, I have a table and when I sort it by `relevancy DESC` it ranks like this:

```
product_id  relevancy
90643   98.4
90566   92.2
90494   9.98
90484   9.95
90490   9.8
90467   9.75
90630   9.64
90580   9.53
90533   9.2
90455   9.15
90531   9.07
90689   9.07
90644   85.24
90603   84.34
90534   81.96
```

Why is it ranking 9.98 higher than 85.24? How can I avoid this and sort it the right way?

Comment: dictionary order, you should be ordering by a decimal output field ( not a char/varchar )

Comment: Is relevancy field decimal or varchar?

Comment: The field is VARCHAR. Should I change it to something else?

Comment: Ah! I changed it to DECIMAL 3,2 and now it's working :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Relevancy field is varchar, so sorting will be in dictionary order.
You have to change type of the column to decimal, or convert varchar column to decimal while sorting:

`SELECT product_id, relevancy FROM db_products ORDER BY CAST(relevancy AS decimal(10,2)) DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Based on that answer [MySQL Query Sorting with Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652763/mysql-query-sorting-with-numbers)

You can either:

1. Change `ORDER BY relevancy DESC` to `ORDER BY CAST(relevancy AS FLOAT) DESC`
2. Redefine your DB-Structure so you have decimal(4,2) as your column `relevancy`. The first argument is the total number of digits of precision, and the second argument is the number of digits after the decimal point.

EDIT: I think Andrews comment is worth reading when you consider the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check your relevancy data type. i think it should be "varchare" . change it to float or duble

or use ORDER BY CAST(relevancy AS decimal(10,2)) DESC